# How can I recalculate a route when I move a draggable marker using HERE API 3/3.1?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, maps, here-api

I'm developing a web site using Here maps API 3/3.1 base on this documentation [Route planning and navigation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.17.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html)

I have draggable markers that are adding when I click the map and calculate a route using arrays when are at least two of them.

[image: Screen 1]

When I move the marker to another location, it shows like this

[image: Screen 2]

And finally, to create the new route, I need to add another marker

[image: Screen 3]

As you see, the previous polyline stills on the map instead of moving with my markers. I found this post ([Here Maps API: Detecting when a Marker is dragged and dropped onto a Polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458099/here-maps-api-detecting-when-a-marker-is-dragged-and-dropped-onto-a-polyline)) but I don't know how I can adapt to my website since this belongs to a previous version.

I hope you can help me.

```
// Se declara un array para guardar los puntos en el mapa
    var arregloPuntos = [];
    var contGlobal = 0;


    // Crea las variables de inicio y final de la ruta
    let startMarker;
    let endMarker;

    let routeLine;

    // Variables para guardar info de los clics
    var clickLat, clickLon;


    // Initialize the platform object:
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': 'API-KEY'
    });

    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        maptypes.vector.normal.map,
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: { lng: -101.68, lat: 21.1236 }
        });

    // Enable the event system on the map instance:
    var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

    // Add event listener:
    map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
        // Log 'tap' and 'mouse' events:
        console.log(evt.type, evt.currentPointer.type);
    });

    // Instantiate the default behavior, providing the mapEvents object:
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);


    // Add the click event listener.
    addDraggableMarker(map, behavior);

    // Funcion para agregar marker arrastrable
    function addDraggableMarker(map, behavior) {

        // Evento que crea el marker haciendo clic en el mapa
        map.addEventListener("tap", event => {
            var position = map.screenToGeo(
                event.currentPointer.viewportX,
                event.currentPointer.viewportY);
            // Imprime posicion
            //console.log(position);

            // Agrega las coordenadas del tap en el arreglo
            arregloPuntos.push(position);
            for (var contGlobal in arregloPuntos) {
                contGlobal++;
            }
            console.log(contGlobal);
            console.log(arregloPuntos);

            for (let j = 0; j < arregloPuntos.length; j++) {
                //Crea el marker a partir de la constante position dando lat y lon
                var marker = new H.map.Marker({ lat: arregloPuntos[j].lat, lng: arregloPuntos[j].lng }, {
                    // mark the object as volatile for the smooth dragging
                    volatility: true
                });
            }
            // Ensure that the marker can receive drag events
            marker.draggable = true;
            map.addObject(marker);

            // disable the default draggability of the underlying map
            // and calculate the offset between mouse and target's position
            // when starting to drag a marker object:
            map.addEventListener('dragstart', function (ev) {
                var target = ev.target,
                    pointer = ev.currentPointer;
                if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
                    var targetPosition = map.geoToScreen(target.getGeometry());
                    target['offset'] = new H.math.Point(pointer.viewportX - targetPosition.x, pointer.viewportY - targetPosition.y);
                    behavior.disable();
                }
                // Se droppea el contenido, para que pueda tomar los nuevos valores
                arregloPuntos.splice(position);         

            }, false);

            // re-enable the default draggability of the underlying map
            // when dragging has completed
            map.addEventListener('dragend', function (ev) {
                var target = ev.target;
                if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
                    behavior.enable();
                }

                // Se sobre escribe la posicion del marker
                position = map.screenToGeo(
                    event.currentPointer.viewportX,
                    event.currentPointer.viewportY);

                //arregloPuntos.splice(position);
                arregloPuntos.push(marker.getGeometry());
                console.log(contGlobal);
                console.log(arregloPuntos);      

                // Metodos de prueba para verificar el cambio en posición
                // marker.getGeometry obtiene los valores de lat y lon del marcador, incluso si este se mueve
                // Defecto: Cada vez que se arrastra el mapa despues de que se agrega un marcador, la consola
                // imprimira las coordenadas cuando se atrastre el mapa, ya que el API las detecta como la
                // funcion drag
                console.log(marker.getGeometry());
            }, false);

            // Listen to the drag event and move the position of the marker
            // as necessary
            map.addEventListener('drag', function (ev) {
                var target = ev.target,
                    pointer = ev.currentPointer;
                if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
                    target.setGeometry(map.screenToGeo(pointer.viewportX - target['offset'].x, pointer.viewportY - target['offset'].y));
                }
            }, false);             

            for (let i = 0; i < arregloPuntos.length; i++) {

                var routingParameters = {
                    'routingMode': 'fast',
                    'transportMode': 'car',
                    // The start point of the route:
                    'origin': '',
                    // The end point of the route:
                    'destination': '',
                    // Include the route shape in the response
                    'return': 'polyline'
                };

                if (i < arregloPuntos.length - 1 && arregloPuntos.length > 0) {

                    routingParameters.origin = arregloPuntos[i].lat + ',' + arregloPuntos[i].lng;
                    startMarker = routingParameters.origin;

                    routingParameters.destination = arregloPuntos[i + 1].lat + ',' + arregloPuntos[i + 1].lng;
                    endMarker = routingParameters.destination;


                    // Define a callback function to process the routing response:
                    var onResult = function (result) {
                        // ensure that at least one route was found
                        if (result.routes.length) {
                            result.routes[0].sections.forEach((section) => {
                                // Create a linestring to use as a point source for the route line
                                let linestring = H.geo.LineString.fromFlexiblePolyline(section.polyline);

                                // Create a polyline to display the route:
                                routeLine = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
                                    style: { strokeColor: 'black', lineWidth: 3 }
                                });

                                // Add the route polyline and the two markers to the map:
                                map.addObjects([routeLine, startMarker, endMarker]);

                                // Set the map's viewport to make the whole route visible:
                                map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({ bounds: routeLine.getBoundingBox() });

                            });
                        }
                    };

                } else {
                    // No tener puesto alguno de estos da un error de Bad request
                    routingParameters.origin = arregloPuntos[i].lat + ',' + arregloPuntos[i].lng;

                    routingParameters.destination = arregloPuntos[i].lat + ',' + arregloPuntos[i].lng;
                }

                // Get an instance of the routing service version 8:
                var router = platform.getRoutingService(null, 8);

                // Call calculateRoute() with the routing parameters,
                // the callback and an error callback function (called if a
                // communication error occurs):
                router.calculateRoute(routingParameters, onResult,
                    function (error) {
                        alert(error.message);
                    });

                //console.log(arregloPuntos[0].lat);
            }

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example of marker drag that you've mentioned, you will have to call the routing API in the `dragend` callback. To clear the previous route, when you draw the route from a polyline, add the polyline to a group first. and then use `groupName.removeAll();`

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find examples:

[Routing with Directions](https://github.com/heremaps/examples/blob/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/directions-rendering-component/a-to-b-with-directions.html) - demonstrates the use of a custom directions renderer component to display maneuver instructions on the page.

https://github.com/heremaps/examples

Comment: I've been trying to find some examples in Here tech github. The problem is that HERE API it's so sensitive and many of the previous version functions does not work in the current version. I found that I can use a group to turn the polyline into a object and delete the route line. Now, when I use that, I can't drop the marker and the route line will be remove every time that I drag the map.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/resizable-geoshapes/resizable-polyline. You can add multiple intermediate points in Polyline object. Every time if there is multiple destinations, then polyline object can be altered.